# Checking my understanding of the identity theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f$ is an analytic function on a domain $\Omega$, $z_0\in\Omega$, $r>0$ and $D_r(z_0)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}| |z-z_0|<r\}\subset\Omega$.

Also, suppose $(f(z))^2=1$, $\forall z\in D_r(z_0)$.

**Claim:** Either $f(z)=1$,$\forall z\in \Omega$ or $f(z)=-1$,$\forall z\in \Omega$.

I'd appreciate if someone could check the validity of my reasoning.

**Reasoning**:

$\forall z\in D_r(z_0)$, $f(z)=1$ or $f(z)=-1$.

By continuity of $f$, $f$ cannot have values $1$ or $-1$ only $D_r(z_0)$.

Without loss of generality, assume that $\forall z\in D_r(z_0)$, $f(z)=1$.

Since there is an accumulation point in $D_r(z_0)$ (in fact all points in $D_r(z_0)$ are accumulation points), $f(z)=1$, $\forall z\in\Omega$, by the identity theorem.

Similarly, if  $\forall z\in D_r(z_0)$, $f(z)=-1$ then $f(z)=-1$, $\forall z\in\Omega$

Comment: Ah, @Snaw. Thanks. My sloppiness. Will delete!

Comment: It is continuity of $f$ and connectedness of $D_r(z_0)$ that implies that $f$ must be constant on $D_r(z_0)$: Since $D_r(z_0)$ is connected, $f(D_r(z_0))$ is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fine. The only part I'd explain a little more about is the part where you use continuity.

Assume by contradiction that there exist $w,z\in D_r(z_0)$ such that $f(w)=1$ and $f(z)=-1$. Since $D_r(z_0)$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, $f(D_r(z_0))\subset\mathbb{R}$ is connected so it is an interval. It contains $1$ and $-1$ by assumption so it must contain all points in between, contradicting the fact that the image of $f$ is just $\pm 1$.

The contradiction implies that either $f(z)=1$ for all $z\in D_r(z_0)$ or $f(z)=-1$ for all $z\in D_r(z_0)$, and the proof continues as you wrote it.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks, this makes the argument clearer. I edited the answer.